# Why does this if/else statement appear to be optimized away?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, compiler-optimization

This is the code in question:

```
    void DeckTug::StickCallback(unsigned long long evtID, DWORD value)
{
    long int val = value;


    if (evtID == stickXInputID || evtID == stickAxisXInputID)
        stickXpct = (((double)val)) / 325.94;
    else if (evtID == stickYInputID || evtID == stickAxisYInputID) {
        stickYpct = (((double)val)) / 325.94;
        if(isAuto)
        if ((stickYpct < 0.0)) {
            acPullingTug = true;
            tugTBoffset = tugReversed ? towbarAttachAft * (-1.0) : towbarAttachForward;
        }
        else {
            acPullingTug = false;
            tugTBoffset = tugReversed ? towbarAttachAft * (-1.0) : towbarAttachForward;
        }
    }
}
```

When I compile a debug build, this runs perfectly. When I compile a release build, it does not work. When I attach the visual studio debugger to the release version, I can break on the first if statement and on the closing brace of the function, but I cannot hit a break point anywhere else, and neither stickXpct or stickYpct are ever being assigned anything, although in the debugger I can see that "value" has a valid value, and "evtID" DOES equal one of inputIDs.
In conclusion, it looks to me like, in the release version of the code only, both the first "if" statement and the first "else if" statement only evaluate to false, even when one of them should evaluate to true. Does anyone know what is going on here? because I don't.

Thanks so much,
Farley

Comment: your wild casts are a bit suspicuous, I am not sure at all, but UB due to one of the casts could be a reason

Comment: `long int val = *reinterpret_cast<long int *>(&value);` invokes *undefined behavior*

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve].   As is, the code refers to variables (class members) that could be anything - and, more importantly, their types and values could be relevant to the effect you're seeing.  That `reinterpret_cast` is highly suspicious though.  The need for all the other type conversions are potentially danger signs.   I'd bet there is some undefined or unspecified behaviour in there somewhere - in which case, the compiler is allowed to do strange things.

Comment: There is not enough code to give conclusive answer, but it looks like UB somewhere. Could be your liberal casts, could be something else.

Comment: By the way, `long int val = *reinterpret_cast<long int *>(&value);` is completely unnecessary - `long int val = value` will be perfect.

Comment: Thanks lads. I removed the suspicious casts, and the problem remains just the same.

Comment: Wrap all the blocks controlled by your if statements in {}, see if that fixes it. Keep doing that until the sight of an if statement without a {} block makes you viscerally uncomfortable.

Comment: @Tzalumen No luck, my friend, unfortunately

Comment: Have you enabled all the compiler warnings?  That could point out something the compiler finds suspicious.

Comment: @Eljay good call, I'll give it a try...

Answer (score 1):

Edit: changed answer in response to comments

Try adding volatility

```
void DeckTug::StickCallback(unsigned long long evtID, DWORD value)
{
    long int val = value;
    volatile unsigned long long _evtID = evtID;


    if (_evtID == stickXInputID || _evtID == stickAxisXInputID)
        stickXpct = (((double)val)) / 325.94;
    else if (_evtID == stickYInputID || _evtID == stickAxisYInputID) {
        stickYpct = (((double)val)) / 325.94;
        if(isAuto)
            if ((stickYpct < 0.0)) {
                acPullingTug = true;
                tugTBoffset = tugReversed ? towbarAttachAft * (-1.0) : towbarAttachForward;
            }
            else {
                acPullingTug = false;
                tugTBoffset = tugReversed ? towbarAttachAft * (-1.0) : towbarAttachForward;
            }
    }
}
```

That should prevent the compiler from optimizing those branches until you can track down why it *wants* to optimize those branches away.

Comment: I thought of trying that, but I can't use a switch statement because stickXInputID etc. are not constants, they're static member variables (of type DWORD). So I can't use them as switch cases.

Comment: Then we're back to https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
It's going to be next to impossible to determine the cause with such a limited sample.

Comment: @lequinne If they are static _const_ DWORD member variables initialized in the class definition then they are constants, and can be used in case labels.

Comment: @Oktalist They're not const, they are returned to this class from somewhere else, during the class constructor. Am currently working on an MCVE, but not sure if I can do it, as the calling code for this function is actually pretty complex... This function is actually a std::function object bound to this class instance, stored in a vector in another object, and called by that object. I'm trying to make a minimal/reproduce-able example, but so far nothing I've tried reproduces the problem, which is not really surprising as I've been using this model for years with no problem.

Comment: In the short term, you can try to force the compiler to not optimize by using `volatile`.

Comment: Also please, for the sake of maintainability, put the code after `if(isAuto)` inside {}

Comment: volatile did not fix the issue, but it at least allowed me to examine all the values in the debugger... the values I'm comparing in the if statement very definitely appear equal, and everything seems very normal. What fixed the issue was changing the 4 static class members ("stickXinputID" etc.) to non-static member variables. Absolutely no idea why that changes anything at all. It's not an initialization thing, because in the debugger, all values appeared correct. Any ideas?

Comment: It's possible that the compiler assumed the values were unchanging since they don't get redefined until runtime. maybe if they were also set volatile that would fix it? I'm not sure how making them instance-specific will affect your baseline.

Comment: @Tzalumen Yes, declaring those inputID variables as "static volatile" did the trick, and allows me to keep them static which is desirable for outside reasons. It's an unsatisfying solution, because I still don't understand why I need them declared volatile, but the compiler-optimized version does work correctly now.

Comment: Most likely, the compiler has decided that `stickYInputID` or `stickAxisYInputID` have the same binary values as `stickXInputID` or `stickAxisXInputID` and that when `else if` evaluates to true it implies the `if` evaluates to true. To me, that suggests there is some overlap in the allowed or initialized values, since the compiler can only make a best guess at the runtime values.